# A Banach space is normal!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I am wondering whether or not a Banach space is normal?

It follows from a proposition that a metric space is normal, so is a Banach space.
Is there any mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mistake. Banach spaces are indeed metric spaces, which are normal.